# Жаба ДАВИТ и жаба ДУШИТ. Как правильно и в чем разница?

Tags: этимология, жаргон, фразеология

***Жаба давит*** человека с незапамятных времён... Рождённый ползать летать не может. **То жаба душит**, то жалость гложет...

1. Хотелось бы понять: жаба ДАВИТ и жаба ДУШИТ — в чём разница? Как правильно?  Есть ли различия в употреблении?
2. Необходимо ли при написании использовать кавычки?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба варианта корректны. Говорить о правильности можно лишь с точки зрения происхождения, исходного смысла. С этой точки зрения "правильнее" будет "жаба давит".

Я исхожу из того, что "жаба" в этом выражении - грудная, народное название стенокардии. Приступы нестабильной стенокардии описываются обычно как **давящая** боль в груди. Отсюда, видимо, и появилось выражение "жаба давит".

Впрочем, оба значения жабы (земноводное и заболевание) восходят к одному индоевропейскому морфу, а в выражениях "жаба душит/давит" иногда усматривают самостоятельное значение - "зависть", происхождение которого можно возвести и к земноводному и к заболеванию. При этом "жаба" как заболевание не ограничивается "грудной". В связи со всем этим "жаба душит" тоже имеет некоторые основания считаться первичным.

В любом случае нормативны, как уже сказали, оба варианта.

Answer (score 1):

А мне кажется, отличаются. В литературе **жаба душит** - проявление жадности, нежелания платить за что-то, даже если это что-то действительно необходимо. Соотвественно, *жаба задушила*, поэтому скряга не приобрёл нужной вещи и пострадал (пошёл пешком по грязной весенней дороге, чтобы не платить извозчику). **Жаба давит** - о зависти, хотя встречается, навскидку, реже аналогичных *побелел от зависти*, *как белены объелся* и прочих.

В обоих случаях словосочетания будут фразеологизмами, поэтому их не нужно обрамлять кавычками.

Answer (score 0):

Словари говорят, что это одно и то же. Хотя некоторые словари говорят, что "жаба давит" только от зависти.
Пишется без кавычек (проверено гугл-книгами и национальным корпусом), полагаю, как и прочие фразеологизмы типа "собаку съел".